# How can i save the value of the date on datepicker jquery UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

As asked before, i want to save the selected date on the datepicker in a value. So as recommended i did the following.

```
$( function() {
    var date_choisie = $("#calendrier").datepicker({ dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd" }).val();
    $( "#calendrier" ).datepicker('setDate', new Date());
    console.log(date_choisie);
} );
```

But nothing is appearing when i'm doing the console.log of currenDate, not even a warning or an error.

Any suggestions why?
Thanks

Comment: please provide some more code and the link to the other question you are talking about

Comment: you want get date on selected date or the current date value saved in a variable ?

Comment: Sorry, i want to console.log(date_choisie) and nothing is appearing when i console.log it

Comment: yeah that what i asked you want to get the date which is in datepicker correct ? it will be `2020-09-20` - right ?

Comment: Well actually it will be 19-09-2020 but yes u got it. Or maybe 20-09-2020, it depends of where you live. Notice i changed the format to dd-mm-yy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You `logic` is **not** correct to get the date from `datePicker` - To get the date which is showing in the `jQuery ui datepicker` currently you can use `native` function of date-picker [getDate](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-getDate)

Once you have date you can `format` it using `formatDate` method to whatever you would like to save it as! It will be saved in the `variable` which can `accessed` for other things if required.

```
//get date in a variable
var date_choisie = $('#calendrier').datepicker('getDate');
var formatDate = $.datepicker.formatDate("yy-mm-dd", date_choisie);
console.log(formatDate); //2020-09-20
```

**Live Working Demo:**

```js
$(function() {
  $("#calendrier").datepicker({
    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
  })
  //set date as current
  $("#calendrier").datepicker('setDate', new Date());

  //get date in a varoable
  var date_choisie = $('#calendrier').datepicker('getDate');
  var formatDate = $.datepicker.formatDate("yy-mm-dd", date_choisie);
  console.log(formatDate); //2020-09-20
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

<p>Date: <input type="text" id="calendrier"></p>
```

Comment: Btw, i can now use formatdate to tringger things based on formatdate?

Comment: @samaywise So you meant that you want to see the updated date in the console.log when you make a change in the calender date ?

Comment: Yes that is it, exactly. I think the onSelect method might help

Comment: @samaywise yes, in that we need to use onSelect method in the `datepicker` and save the selected date in a variable :)

Comment: @samaywise Here is working fiddle for you => https://jsfiddle.net/trqn7akL/ - check console.log it will show the selected date.

Comment: However, i need the two dates in the same variable, i need the first one console.logged which is the currentdate get cruched by the selected one if the user changes the date. I need this because i am transfering this date variable in php by using Ajax so i can show data dynamically.